# How to access post data when name is variable in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, variables, post

I have checkboxes. Their names are the results from a query. I want to insert their values in database, but I can't access them. I tried with $this->input->post($userId) but it doesn't work. How could I access them?

When I echo in my view:

```
 echo $this->input->post($userId) ;
```

it shows these user_ids. But how to access them in Model?

My view is:

```html
<?php    
        

foreach ($all_teachers_show as $row)
{


$userId = $row->user_id;
     echo  $userId;
$first_name = $row->first_name;
$last_name = $row->last_name;
$teacherSelected = ( isset($_POST[$userId]) ) ? true : false;

?>

<td>
<input
type="checkbox"
class='all_teachers_show'
name="<?php echo $userId; ?>"
<?php
if ( $teacherSelected )
echo 'checked="checked"';
?>
value="<?php echo $userId; ?>"
>
<?php echo $first_name . ' ' . $last_name ?>
<td>
```

Comment: Why don't you change the "name" attribute to be like: name="user_ids[<?php echo $userId; ?>"] Then in your model you can access them like: $userIds = $_POST['user_ids']; and that will be an array.

Comment: I tried with: name="user_ids[<?php echo $userId; ?>]" as you said, in my model wrote: if ($this->input->post('user_ids[]')) {
          
            foreach ($this->input->post('user_ids[]') as $teacher)
            {
                $data = array(
                    'teacher_id' => $teacher,
                    'coordinator_id' => $insert_id,
                    'created_at'=>$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                );

              
                $this->db->insert('coordinator_teacher_conn', $data);

            }   but it didn't insert it.

Comment: $this->input->post('user_ids[]') should be $this->input->post('user_ids') or $_POST['user_ids']; also please use log_message to see if you are getting all the fields as expected in the foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and I'll write

Comment: It inserts values now. But how to change this: $teacherSelected = ( isset($_POST[$userId]) ) ? true : false;   to select selected options?

Comment: $teacherSelected = (isset($_POST['user_ids'][$userId]))? true : false; should do the job